# How to set up a for loop to append any word with punctuation with as a key with an empty value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, punctuation

I am trying to use code to develop a Markov chain that will create random sentences from a string. I have already split the string and am evaluating it. My current code is:

```
#Your code here
string = '''how much wood could a woodchuck chuck
if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
as much wood as a woodchuck could chuck
if a woodchuck could chuck wood.'''
st_dict={}

for i in range(0, len(words)-1):
  #print(words)
  word=words[i]
  next_word=words[i+1]
  if word in ['.','?']:
    st_dict[word]=[]
  elif word in st_dict:
    st_dict[word].append(next_word)
  else:
    st_dict[word]=[next_word]
st_dict[words[-1]]=[]
print(st_dict)
```

However, any word that has punctuation in it should only have a null list as its value. However, I cannot get this to work. I have tried:
word not in ['.','?'... etc] in addition to the if statement above, but words with punctuation in the middle of the string still append the next word as a value. How do I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap your code in a function, provide example input, and current output and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word in ['.','?']` will only be true if `word` is **exactly** `'.'` or **exactly** `'?'`.

You want the opposite: `'.' in word or '?' in word`.

If you have a list of punctuation then you should use `any`:

```
punctuation = ".?"
any(punct in word for punct in punctuation)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Simple, I tried ```if '." or '?' in word...```, but I keep forgetting that the logic of the code is not the same as the logic of our informal language.